# MongoDB document model size/performance limits? A collection with an object that possibly houses 100k+ names?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to build an event website that will host videos and such.  I've set up a collection with the event name, event description, and an object with some friendly info of people "attending".  If things go well there might be 100-200k people attending, and those people should have access to whoever else is in the event.  (clicking on the friendly name will find the user's id and subsequently their full profile)  Is that asking too much of mongo?  Or is there a better way to go about doing something like that?  It seems like that could get rather large rather quick.

```
{
    _id : ...., // event Id,
    'name' :  // event name
    'description' : //event description
    'attendees' :{
        {'username': user's friendly name, 'avatarlink': avatar url},
        {'username': user's friendly name, 'avatarlink': avatar url},
        {'username': user's friendly name, 'avatarlink': avatar url},
        {'username': user's friendly name, 'avatarlink': avatar url}
    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB many-to-many modeling (or one-to-many) in general, you should take a different approach depending if the many are **few** (up to few dozens usually) or "really" **many** as in your case.

It will be better for you not to use embedding in your case, and instead normalize. If you embed users in your events collection, adding attendees to a certain event will increase the array size. Since documents are updated in-place, if the document can't fit it's disk size, it will have to moved on disk, a very expensive operation which will also cause fragmentation. There are [few techniques](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-manual-padding) to deal with moves, but none is ideal.

Having a array of `ObjectId` as attendees will be better in that documents will grow much less dramatically, but still issue few problems. How will you find all events user has participated in? You can have a multi-key index for attendees, but once a certain document moves, the index will have to be updated per each user entry (the index contains a pointer to the document place on disk). In your case, where you plan to have up to 200K of users it will be very very painful.

Embedding is a very cool feature of MongoDB or any other document oriented database, but it's naive to think it doesn't (sometimes) comes without a price.

I think you should really rethink your schema: having an events collection, a users collection and a user_event collection with a structure similar to this:

```
{
     _id : ObjectId(),
     user_id : ObjectId(),
     event_id : ObjectId()
}
```

**Normalization is not a dirty word**

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I'm still new to the Mongo world and wasn't sure if that went against the concept.  You're correct though that this can quickly turn into a large many-to-many relationship.  I do already have a Users collection and if a person viewed the event they could click on a name and that would do a search for the id and fill out the rest of the profile.  My original thinking was that it would be easier if everything needed in the Event view was available in the event object, but I think I agree with you that it needs to be broken out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider modeling your data in two collections and your attendees field in an event document would be an array of user ids.

Here's a sample of the schema:

db.events

```
{
    _id : ...., // event Id,
    'name' :  // event name
    'description' : //event description
    'attendees' :[ObjectId('userId1'), ObjectId('userId2') ...]
}
```

db.users

```
{
    _id : ObjectId('userId1'),
    username: 'user friendly name',
    avatarLink: 'url to avatar'
}
```

Then you could do 2 separate queries

```
db.events.find({_id: ObjectId('eventId')});
db.users.find( {_id: {$in: [ObjectId['userId1'), ObjectId('userId2')]}});
```

Comment: So I do have a Users collection already.  I was only storing the username and avatar url because that was something that would be available in the Event view.  When looking at the event you should be able to see the people attending.  If they choose to find out more about that user then they can click on their name which will search for the userid of that name and return the entire profile.  My original thought was not to make another query if you just want to see the basics of people attending.  Does that help or change your recommendation?